# Awk with multiple delimiters

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to execute `awk` on something like this :

```
<tag x="whatever" y="http://mysite.com/somewords/word1/word2/word3/word4">
```

I would like to extract `word2` which comes forever after `word1`, knowing that `somewords` does not always exist.

I was able to do it using `awk`, but I used it 3 times, each time with one delimiter.

Is there any way to merge multiple `awk` commands with multiple delimiters, or simply one `awk` command to pick out `word2`?

Comment: Why not posted the `awk` codes you wish to merge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The awk delimiter can be a regular expression, so if you want to split the line on, say, spaces and slashes, you can use `-F '[ /]'`

But, given your sketchy description, you may just need this:

```
awk -F/ '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if ($i == "word1") {print $(i+1); break}}'
```